# How to reload script without refresh and compile directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing issue in script tag. I added script dynamically and not able to compile directive and not able to access the controller.

For example:

```
var dynamicScript = true;

if(dynamicScript) {
document.body.appendChild(<script src = "filepath"/>);
}
```

And now, Angular click action I need to compile directive. but directive is not compiled.

Comment: So what problem  you faced to compile the directive? Use `$compile`

Comment: Many script loaders inject script tags just like you have show. They work fine.

Comment: Hi, did you resolve it?

Answer (score -1):

```
 document.write('<script src = "filepath"><\/script>');
```

If you write like this browser automatically load script file from src path then automatically compiles.